Official SEH example does not compile with mingw-w64
Hi I got this example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-se-translator?view=msvc-170
// crt_set_se_translator_clr.cpp
// compile with: cl /W4 /clr crt_set_se_translator_clr.cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <eh.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>

int thrower_func( int i ) {
   int y = 0;
   int *p = &y;
   *p = i / *p;
   return 0;
}

class SE_Exception : public std::exception
{
private:
    const unsigned int nSE;
public:
    SE_Exception() noexcept : SE_Exception{ 0 } {}
    SE_Exception( unsigned int n ) noexcept : nSE{ n } {}
    unsigned int getSeNumber() const noexcept { return nSE; }
};

class Scoped_SE_Translator
{
private:
    const _se_translator_function old_SE_translator;
public:
    Scoped_SE_Translator( _se_translator_function new_SE_translator ) noexcept
        : old_SE_translator{ _set_se_translator( new_SE_translator ) } {}
    ~Scoped_SE_Translator() noexcept { _set_se_translator( old_SE_translator ); }
};

#pragma unmanaged
void my_trans_func( unsigned int u, PEXCEPTION_POINTERS )
{
    throw SE_Exception( u );
}

void DoTest()
{
    try
    {
        thrower_func( 10 );
    }
    catch( const SE_Exception& e )
    {
        printf( "Caught SE_Exception, error %8.8x\n", e.getSeNumber() );
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        printf( "Caught unexpected SEH exception.\n" );
    }
}
#pragma managed

int main() {
    Scoped_SE_Translator scoped_se_translator{ my_trans_func };

    DoTest();
}

I tried to compile with mingw-w64 on my Windows 10 x64 pro laptop (msys2 installation).
g++ gnu_better_seh.cc

gcc details:
c:\work>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/winoss/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-14.2.0/configure --prefix=/ucrt64 --with-local-prefix=/ucrt64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/ucrt64/include --libexecdir=/ucrt64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,rust,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/ucrt64 --with-mpfr=/ucrt64 --with-mpc=/ucrt64 --with-isl=/ucrt64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-plugin --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 14.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)

but I get
c:\work>g++ gnu_better_seh.cc
C:/winoss/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\VASILI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccprbtUh.o:gnu_better_seh:(.text$_ZN20Scoped_SE_TranslatorC1EPFvjP19_EXCEPTION_POINTERSE[_ZN20Scoped_SE_TranslatorC1EPFvjP19_EXCEPTION_POINTERSE]+0x1a): undefined reference to `__imp__Z18_set_se_translatorPFvjP19_EXCEPTION_POINTERSE'
C:/winoss/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\VASILI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccprbtUh.o:gnu_better_seh:(.text$_ZN20Scoped_SE_TranslatorD1Ev[_ZN20Scoped_SE_TranslatorD1Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `__imp__Z18_set_se_translatorPFvjP19_EXCEPTION_POINTERSE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

what is the issue? How can it be modified?

It builds when _set_se_translator is defined with extern "C"
Here's what I did:
Edit mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/eh.h to change the line
_CRTIMP _se_translator_function __cdecl _set_se_translator(_se_translator_function _NewPtFunc);

to:
extern "C" _CRTIMP _se_translator_function __cdecl _set_se_translator(_se_translator_function _NewPtFunc);

And then I build with
g++ gnu_better_seh.cc -lvcruntime140_app

or
g++ gnu_better_seh.cc -lucrtbase

